# foreign key error While submitting the forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I had created a model and it contain foreign key fields also , but while I try to submit it shows error by saying like number cannot assign to the field where foreign key is assigned. I had submited models.py , forms.py , views.py below. Please go through it How can I upload as name . Error picture  like below [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYOg5.png)

> models.py:

```py
class UserReg(models.Model):
    username=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Date_of_Birth=models.DateField()
    Age=models.IntegerField()
    Gender=models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=GenderChoice)
    Phone_no=models.IntegerField()
    Mail=models.EmailField(unique=True)
    Address=models.TextField(max_length=700)
    District=models.ForeignKey(District,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Branch=models.ForeignKey(Branch,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Account_Type=models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=AccType)
    Materials=models.ManyToManyField(Materials)


class District(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

> Views.py:

```py
def reg(request):
    form = Userform(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        Name = request.POST.get('Name')
        Date_of_Birth = request.POST.get('Date_of_Birth')
        Age = request.POST.get('Age')
        Gender = request.POST.get('Gender')
        Phone_no = request.POST.get('Phone_no')
        Mail = request.POST.get('Mail')
        Address = request.POST.get('Address')
        District = request.POST.get('District')
        Branch = request.POST.get('Branch')
        Account_Type = request.POST.get('Account_Type')
        Materials = request.POST.get('Materials')
        obj = UserReg(username=username, Name=Name, Date_of_Birth=Date_of_Birth, Age=Age, Gender=Gender,
                      Phone_no=Phone_no, Mail=Mail, Address=Address, District=District, Branch=Branch, Account_Type=Account_Type, Materials=Materials)
        obj.save()
        return redirect('/')

    return render(request, 'registration.html', {'form': form})
```

> template part:

```
<div class="form-row">
                        <div class="name">District</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="col-sm ">
                                <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                {{form.District}}
                                <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

> forms.py

```
class Userform(forms.ModelForm):
Gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GenderChoice)
Account_Type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AccType)
District = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=District.objects.all())
Branch = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Branch.objects.all())
class Meta:
    model = UserReg
    fields = ['username','Name','Date_of_Birth','Age','Gender','Phone_no',
              'Mail','Address','District','Branch','Account_Type', 'Materials']
    widgets = {
        'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','readonly':'readonly'}),
        'Name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg input--style-5'}),
        'Date_of_Birth':DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-lg input--style-5'}),
        'Age':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg input--style-5'}),
        'Gender':forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':' form-check-input input--style-5 '}),
        'Phone_no':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg input--style-5'}),
        'Mail':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg input--style-5','type':'email'}),
        'Address':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control input--style-5','rows':'4'}),
        'District':forms.Select(),
        'Branch':forms.Select(),
        'Account_Type':forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class':'form-check form-check-input input--style-5'}),
        'Materials':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'form-check form-check-input input--style-5'}),
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you must have `District` associated with `District` model, it must be the instance, share the template.

Comment: <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">District</div>

                                <div class="value">
                                    <div class="col-sm ">

                                    <div class="rs-select2 js-select-simple select--no-search">
                                    {{form.District}}
                                        <div class="select-dropdown"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         </div>

Comment: You haven't also closed one of your `div` in html, I suppose, check it and also after my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73446526/17562044) if it returns same error for `branch` field then do same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to assign an integer to the foreign key field. The value returned from the form will be a foreign key (an integer, as it's the id field in this question), while the foreign key field takes the instance itself as an argument.

Try to assign this in the field:

```py
district = District.objects.get(pk=District)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says assign actual instance of `District` model instead of "5".

So, first fetch district instance from `District` model through [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) then assign it to `UserReg` model, so:

If found nothing, it will raise Http404 error.

```
def reg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_reg=form.save(commit=False)
            user_reg.save()
            user_reg.save_m2m()
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form=UserForm()          

    return render(request,'registration.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: It shows "No District matches the given query." What should I do now

Comment: @elhalcon That means you have no district with the value coming from html. Try to give those districts which actually exist in the model.

Comment: It shows same error in ever district, but o problem while we add through admin page

Comment: @elhalcon Share your `UserForm`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247513/discussion-between-el-halcon-and-sunderam-dubey).